# indexing rows in matrix using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, cell

Suppose I have an empty m-by-n-by-p dimensional cell called "cellPoints", and I also have a D-by-3 dimensional array called "cellIdx" where each row i contains the subscripts in "cellPoints". Now I want to compute "cellPoints" so that cellPoints{x, y, z} contains an array of row numbers in "cellIdx".

A naive implementation could be

```
for i = 1:size(cellIdx, 1)
    cellPoints{cellIdx(i, 1), cellIdx(i, 2), cellIdx(i, 3)} = ...
    [cellPoints{cellIdx(i, 1), cellIdx(i, 2), cellIdx(i, 3)};i];
end
```

As an example, suppose

```
cellPoints = cell(10, 10, 10);% user defined, cannot change
cellIdx = [1, 3, 2;
           3, 2, 1;
           1, 3, 2;
           1, 4, 2]
```

Then

```
cellPoints{1, 3, 2} = [1;3];
cellPoints{3, 2, 1} = [2];
cellPoints{1, 4, 2} = [4];
```

and other indices of cellPoints should be empty

Since cellIdx is a large matrix and this is clearly inefficient, are there any other better implementations?

I've tried using unique(cellIdx, 'rows') to find unique rows in cellIdx, and then writing a for-loop to compute cellPoints, but it's even slower than above.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Post some example input and output

Comment: @LuisMendo an example is provided now

Comment: Your code applied to the given `cellIdx` does not work. `cellPoints` should also be defined for your code to run

Comment: Oh, I think I got what  you want

Comment: @LuisMendo I tried using [~, ~, kk] = unique(cellIdx, 'rows', 'stable'); cellPoints = accumarray(kk, 1:numel(kk), [], @(x) {sort(x)}); It worked, but size(cellPoints) should be user defined and only some of the indices are filled. See my edited examples. (Sorry again for the confusion, my bad!)

Comment: No, that was my bad. That was clear from your question. Please see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is faster:

```
cellPoints = cell(10,10,10); %// initiallize to proper size
[~, jj, kk] = unique(cellIdx, 'rows', 'stable')
sz = size(cellPoints);
sz = [1 sz(1:end-1)];
csz = cumprod(sz).'; %'// will be used to build linear index
ind = 1+(cellIdx(jj,:)-1)*csz; %// linear index to fill cellPoints
cellPoints(ind) = accumarray(kk, 1:numel(kk), [], @(x) {sort(x)});
```

Or remove `sort` from the last line if order within each cell is not important.